# Is another user's edit to an on-hold question enough to trigger reopening?

Tags: discussion, questions, on-hold

I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215884/how-is-postgresql-different-than-mysql) for the first time and it was edited by another user. However, I read that if a question becomes [on hold] then it requires editing within five days to reopen it.

Do I need to take action after the other user edited my question or is that other user's edit considered sufficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An edit by anyone leads to the question being reviewed. Which may lead to the question being reopened **if** five members agree it is now on topic.

However, the existing edit is pretty superficial. Really there needs to be a lot more done to make it not primarily opinion based. It also has several questions in one, which isnt good.

The primary factual part of the question is on whether the syntaxes are the same (Although even that is a little broad). I would focus on those elements. Which is "better" or if your knowledge is sufficent is highly unlikely to be editable such that it is on topic

Answer (score 0):

You should only wait to see if other users with high rep decide to reopen or to keep closed your question. SO requires editing in general and not editing by the OP.

Comment: my question is apparently marked as opinion based. So is a closed question considered the same as deleted/will be deleted or is that only a category that has some restrictions but will remain accessible?

Comment: @Sahl closed: everybody can view/ deleted: special users (high rep and OP) can view. Closed question != deleted.

Comment: @Sahl Closed/on hold basically means that no new answers can be posted